# Publishing an azure web service takes 30 min or more? Is this normal?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

The azure powershell command [Publish-AzureServiceProject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/publish-azureserviceproject?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) is taking upto 30min or more to successfully publish an application. We run the following azure powershell command.

```
Publish-AzureServiceProject  
    -Package
    'C:\tca\tick\712fd6c47ab9a6e5\azurewebsite\Weingartner.Distribution.Azure.cspkg' 
    -Slot Staging 
    -Configuration
    'C:\tca\tick\712fd6c47ab9a6e5\azurewebsite\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg'
```

which results in the following output

```
      Id                                       Type Subscriptions                        Tenants                             
      --                                       ---- -------------                        -------                             
      research@weingartnergmbh.onmicrosoft.com User XXXXXXX {XXXXXXXXXXX...

       14:28:50 - Verifying storage account 'weingartnerdistribution'...
       Publishing weingartnerdistribution to Microsoft Azure. This may take several minutes...
       14:28:51 - Connecting...
       14:28:53 - Uploading Package to storage service weingartnerdistribution...
       14:29:32 - Starting...
       14:30:37 - Created Deployment ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
       14:30:37 - Initializing...
       15:02:15 - Instance   
                  Weingartner.Distribution.Website.Hosting.Azure_IN_0 
                  of role 
                  Weingartner.Distribution.Website.Hosting.Azure 
                  is busy.
       15:06:24 - Instance 
                  Weingartner.Distribution.Website.Hosting.Azure_IN_0 
                  of role 
                  Weingartner.Distribution.Website.Hosting.Azure 
                  is ready.
       15:06:25 - Created Website URL: http://XXXXXXXXXX.cloudapp.net/.



     Finished Target: Publish
```

It takes 30 minutes to initialize the VM. When I go to the azure portal there are no errors that are obvious and the service runs correctly when eventually it starts.

I would like to ask azure what is going on but as I'm using an **extra small** instance and have no service contract ie:

[image]

Question? Do people with higher paid plans or larger spec virtual machines see the same 30 min turn around for publishing an upgrade to an app service or is this is purely technical problem that can be solved with better usage of the APIs?

## EDIT

I ran the following command at the command line at 7:28am

Publish-AzureServiceProject -Package .\Weingartner.Distribution.Azure.cspkg -Configuration .\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg -Slot Staging

and according to the AzurePortal it finished at 7:38am

[image]

However the debug output from the poweshell script was continually outputting the following until 7:53am GMT+1 ( Sensitive data is erased with XXXXX and note the logs are in GMT so add one hour )

```
Headers:
x-ms-servedbyregion           : ussouth3
Strict-Transport-Security     : max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
x-ms-request-id               : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Cache-Control                 : no-cache
Date                          : Tue, 09 Jan 2018 06:53:31 GMT
Server                        : 1.0.6198.592,(rd_rdfe_stable.180102-1534),Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

Body:
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>s2018-01-09-07-25-41-2872</Name>
  <DeploymentSlot>Staging</DeploymentSlot>
  <PrivateID>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</PrivateID>
  <Status>Running</Status>
  <Label>XXXXXXXXX</Label>
  <Url>http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.cloudapp.net/</Url>
```

Comment: `I get the suspicion that I am being deliberately throttled in order to make me upgrade to a bigger plan.` - I seriously doubt that. Are you running any startup tasks in your application? Or doing something time consuming in your role's OnStart method? That could be the reason why the initializing would take such a long time.

Comment: I pretty sure I'm not doing anything suspicious. I connect to a blob storage in the startup. That is all.

Comment: What are you doing there? Are you downloading some data? Will it be possible to share that code?

Comment: Also, please try to create a deployment through Azure Portal as well and see if you're seeing the same behavior there as well.

Comment: I have a log that proves the ``OnStart`` method of the RoleEntryPoint is not called till 15:04. That line is at https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/964a9458582fada46af689acac96ed34#file-workrole-cs-L38  nothing happens before there apart from connecting the logger to logentries.com.

Comment: Hmmm....The code indeed looks pretty straightforward. Can you try deploying it through Portal?

Comment: I'll try to do that.

Comment: I loaded the cspkg file via the portal, started it and then swapped to production. All in less than 5 minutes. Looks like something is wrong with the powershell scripts. I've been contacted by azure support so I'll take it from there.

Comment: Cool. You can try by adding `-Debug` to your PowerShell script so see more detailed information. Would you mind sharing the result once you have it? I am curious to know about why PowerShell is taking so much time.

Comment: Are there security risks to pasting the output from the -DEBUG here. There seem to be a number of magic tokens and ids in the XML.

Comment: I would imagine. I would remove any GUID looking strings and Bas64 encoded string before pasting the output.

Comment: The result is strange. From the Azure Portal CreateDeploymentBySlot is finished at 7.38 but the powershell script debug output is still getting ``<Status>Running</Status>`` on the deployment status request at 7:53. I will add the relevant bits of the log to the question.